# Counting how many times a condition statement in while loop is ran

Tags: java

This will count how many times the while loop ran **when true**, however, I am trying to count how many times the num==0 test is performed. The num integer will change.

```
int counter = 0;
while (num == 0) {
    doSomething();
    counter ++;
}
```

This is an alternative I came up with, but seeking a better way to do it.

```
int counter = 0;
do {
    if (num == 0) {
        doSomething();
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
} while (num == 0);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but `if (num == 0)` condition is redundant in second, third and later iterations because these would only be execyted when condition at `while (num == 0)` will be true.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but I am trying to count it regardless if num==0 is true or not, and the while loops is just there to call doSomething.

Comment: Since the value of `num` never change here, the check `num==0` will be called infinitely many times. And since infinity plus or minus any number is equal to infinity, any offset errors doesn't matter here and so since counter also will be infinite, you can say that `counter` actually is equals to the number of times the check is performed. Meaning you were already right, but if you want to prove it by running the program, it might take a while.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope My bad for not giving enough context, the num will change.

Answer (score 0):

Given the loop:

```
while (num == 0) {
    doSomething();
    counter ++;
}
```

The check `num==0` will be performed once for every iteration, then once more after the last iteration. That last check is the one that prevents the `while` from being executed again.

So if `counter` is equal to 3, that means that we had 3 full iterations of the loop (3 checks whether `num==0`), followed by a fourth check that prevented us from going into the loop again.

It isn't clear to me what your second code snippet is trying to achieve.

```
if (num == 0) {
    doSomething();
    counter++;
} else {
    counter++;
}
```

Is 100% equivalent to

```
if (num == 0) {
    doSomething();
}
counter++;
```

And after every iteration of the `do...while()` there will still be a check for `num==0` due to the loop condition.

Comment: To my knowledge, if counter is equal to 3, it means that num==0 is true for 3 iterations, not that num==0 is checked 3 times.

Comment: That's the same thing if the condition `num==0` is being checked once per iteration.

Comment: About your second edit, it was trying to call doSomething when num==0 is true, counting it in the meantime, while also counting it if num==0 is false.

Comment: Your second snippet checks `num==0` *twice* for every iteration - once in the `if`, once in the loop condition.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but my main concern is counting num==0 of the while loop. Let me rephrase, I am trying to count how many time num==0 is checked in a while loop, if it was done as like your first snippet, it will only count when num==0 is true. My apologies, english is not my first language.

Comment: @27bch7GbDu What do you mean by *check* in "how many time num==0 is *checked* in a while loop"? Do you want to know how many times `num==0` test is performed or how many times `num==0` was evaluated as `true` (or maybe something else)?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know how many times num==0 test is performed, regardless if it's true or not.

Comment: @27bch7GbDu In your original code that condition is tested only inside `while(..)` section so that test would be performed same amount of times loop iterated (when `num==0` was true) + once when it was evaluated to false and loop exited. So to get proper answer you can change in first example `int counter = 0;` to `int counter = 1;`, OR place additional `counter++` *after* the loop.

Comment: But that didn't answer my question of counting the number of checks. The num is changed in my actual code. I am sorry for not giving enough context.

Comment: "*But that didn't answer my question of counting the number of checks*" actually that is precisely what my comment was about... If it doesn't answer your question then probably I am misunderstanding you somewhere, or you are misunderstanding something in my comment. To reduce those misunderstandings consider editing your question with some *actual* code and based on its execution show and explain "results" you wanted to see/get.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of times a particular **if** condition is checked (inspected) within a **while** loop then place a counter variable (that increments by 1: `counter++;`) directly above that **if** statement line within the loop since any conditional statement can potentially abruptly ***break*** out of or ***continue*** the loop within its code block if that particular condition is true.

This counter variable will need to have been declared and initialized to 0 above the **while** loop. Here is an example:

```
int counter = 0;
while (num == 0) {
    if (doSomething == true) {
        continue;    // counter can not increment. Goes to next iteration.
    }
    if (doOtherThing.equals("no") {
        break;       // counter can not increment. Exits loop.
    }
    counter ++;      // counts the number of times the following IF was checked.
    if (n == 0) {
        doSomthingCool();
        num++;       // increments num to 1 and loop will exit on next iteration attempt.
    }
}
```

The above counter simply indicates that the IF condition following the increment of that counter will definitely be inspected...**not** found to be true and its' code block entered and run. It basically indicates that the condition will definitely be looked at.

This is fine and well until you start dealing with **else if**. What if you wanted to know if the ELSE IF was checked? Was the IF inspected or the ELSE IF? You still don't want to know if the condition was true and the code block for that statement was entered, you just want to know if the condition was looked at and checked.

One way to overcome this situation is to apply the counter directly into the condition for that statement. This can be done but the counter condition portion should always be equal to true and be the first condition encountered followed by **&&** (AND) within the overall conditional statement, this way all other conditions will be checked in their original sequential order:

```
if ((ifCounter == ifCounter++) && someNum < 3) { ... }
else if ((elseCounter = elseCounter++) && someNum < 10) { ... }
```

Here is a runnable example:

```
int num = 0;
int counter = 0;                 // The Overall iteration counter
int doSomethingCounter = 0;      // The doSomething condition counter
int doSomeOtherThingCounter = 0; // The doOtherThing condition counter
int ifCounter = 0;               // The IF someNum condition counter
int elseIfCounter = 0;           // The ELSE IF someNum condition counter
int someNum = 0;
boolean doSomething = true;
String doOtherThing = "yes";

while (num < 10) {
    counter++;
    if ((doSomethingCounter == doSomethingCounter++) && doSomething == true) {
        doSomething = !doSomething;
        continue;    // Counters can not increment. Goes to next iteration.
    }

    if ((doSomeOtherThingCounter == doSomeOtherThingCounter++) && doOtherThing.equals("no")) {
        break;       // Counters can not increment. Exits loop.
    }

    // Counts the number of times the following IF condition was checked.
    if ((ifCounter == ifCounter++) && someNum < 4) {
        someNum = doSomethingCool(someNum);
    }
    // Counts the number of times ELSE IF condition is checked.
    else if ((elseIfCounter == elseIfCounter++) && someNum > 0) {
        /* increments num by 1 until it reaches 10 then loop 
           will exit on next iteration attempt.           */
           num++;
    } 
}

System.out.println("The WHILE loop has done a total of:        " + counter + " iterations.");
System.out.println("The doSomething IF condition was checked:  " + doSomethingCounter + " times.");
System.out.println("The doOtherThing IF condition was checked: " + doSomeOtherThingCounter + " times.");
System.out.println("The someNum IF condition was checked:      " + ifCounter + " times.");
System.out.println("The someNum ELSE IF condition was checked: " + elseIfCounter + " times.");
```

When the above code example is run the console window will display:

```
The WHILE loop has done a total of:        15 iterations.
The doSomething IF condition was checked:  15 times.
The doOtherThing IF condition was checked: 14 times.
The someNum IF condition was checked:      14 times.
The someNum ELSE IF condition was checked: 10 times.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int num = 0;
int counter = 0;
while(num==0) {
    if (num == 0) {
      doSomething();
    } else {
    }
    counter++;
    //if the counter inc then the above condition statement should been executed.Make sure this doesn't take break into consideration.
}
```

Comment: `while(num==0) {
    if (num == 0)` what is the point of `if (num == 0)` when it is first thing after `while(num==0)` which already checks that condition?

Comment: His goal is to see how many time will condition execute in the loop. So i put counter at the end because even if there is continue it will take into consideration.